# How to prevent bootstrap.min.js directly accessed from my angular site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, bootstrap-4, angular-directive

I am trying to directly access **bootstrap.min.js** from my angular 4 website.

www.website.com/solutions/scripts/bootstrap.min.js.

How to prevent access this directly from browser?

Bootstrap library 3.3.7 has known security issue , but even though i upgrade to bootstrap 4.0 , that file `bootstrap.min.js` is still accessible through direct url

I changed

```
 "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "3.3.7",
```

To

```
 "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "4.0.0",
```

Also i changed

```
"bootstrap": "^3.0.0",

"bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
```

Still i can reference the file

Comment: I don't want browser to use bootstrap file or what?

Comment: i want to prevent it from directly accessing from browser, i am not sure it is been used as well.. at least preventing it directly accessing from browser will work for now..how to do that?

Comment: If your browser is using this js file, that means html have some script tag with `src="path_to_js_file"`.

Comment: If you're saying that you don't want people to be able to type in the URL of your bootstrap.js file and view it, you can't. For the file to be available to the browser the user needs to be able to access it. I'm not sure why you're concerned about this.

Comment: @vadim i search eveywhere in the code and not found it using any script tag for this

Comment: @rory thats right i dont want people to able to type in url of bootstrap.min.js , i am not using this and unable to get rid of this

Comment: In that case, as I explained above, you can't stop people viewing it. They *need* to have access to it for it to work. Again, I'm not sure why you're worried about this. It's how the web works.

Comment: its open to xss attacks that why worried

Comment: library 3.3.7  has known security issue , but even though i upgrade to bootstrap 4.0 , that file is still accessible through direct url

Comment: I see easy solution: You have server where all files are located. Static hosting, PHP/Node/Java don't know your variant. But you anyway have access to files on your server so go and just delete this file.

Comment: yes its IIS server in windows

Comment: I tried to locate the file in the IIS root folder, search everywhere there it is not listing there

Comment: looks like i am referencing bootstrap and ngbootstrap together.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add a bootstrap file in your angular project.
Use below command to install bootstrap in your project.
**npm install bootstrap**
and add it inside angular.json

One more option, you can add the bootstrap module

**`npm install bootstrap ngx-bootstrap --save`**

Comment: This may well be good advice, but seems completely irrelevant to what's being asked.

Comment: i have did the same, but still that bootstrap file is referenced , i search the code and not found that file been referenced anywhere

Comment: library 3.3.7 has known security issue , but even though i upgrade to bootstrap 4.0 , that file is still accessible through direct url

Answer (score 0):

Issue was because there is a cached file in IIS, and a restart may fix the issue